# How to use map function in clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, leiningen

I have a function named `f` which supposed to be mapped onto a vector in my main function. However when I `lein run` my code nothing happens...

```
(ns my-proj.core
  (:gen-class))

(def f
  (fn
    [x]
    (println x)))

(def -main
  (fn
    [& args]
    (map f args)))

(-main [1 2 3 4 5])
```

The code seems correct according to the [docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map). But what am I missing? Plz help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My code was incorrect, for starters I should not have passed a vector into the main; then all I had to do was add `doall`. So here's what I wanted in case you also need the `map` to work.

```
(ns my-proj.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn f
  [x]
  (println (+ x 1)))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (doall
    (map f args)))

(-main 1 2 3 4 5)
```

I think what happens is: a vector will be passed as a single argument, so if you add `doall` the `map` will work but it will only print out your vector as one thing. I thought it would be unwrapped by the map.

Comment: If the last function call of a function is `println` then `nil` will be what the function returns. Here `f` is returning `nil`.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy is it bad for a function to return nil? I keep thinking about clojure in terms of javascript where it's not necessarily a bad thing for a function to return nothing.

Comment: Functional programming is all about pure functions that return values. `nil` is a value like any other. `f` is your 'mapping function'. Your mapping function always returns the same value, which is a bad code smell. It should be a pure function that returns a different element to the one that goes in. Otherwise there's no point in calling `map`. Having said all this there is no real problem putting debug statements anywhere you like.

Comment: Your answer is still twisted. Doseq is what you are loking for, a combination of map and doall is useless and suboptimal

Comment: @JosephYourine What would be your optimal answer?

Comment: @JosephYourine useless, like your comment?

Answer (score 1):

Since [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) is lazy, you'll need to use a different approach if you want side effects. In this case, you could use [`run!`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/run!):

```
(run! println [1 2 3 4 5])
;; 1
;; 2
;; 3
;; 4
;; 5
;;=> nil
```

Comment: I don't really want side effects, so you are welcome rewrite this whole thing.

Comment: @user000001 Yes you do, that's exactly what `println` does: it performs the side effect of printing a string followed by a newline to [`*out*`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*out*).

Answer (score 0):

Your function `f` is returning `nil` because `println` returns `nil`. The function `identity` returns the value that it is given. Here I have commented out your `println` call so that `f` effectively becomes `identity`:

```
(def f
  (fn
    [x]
    ;(println x)
    x
    ))

(defn -main [& args]
  (apply map f args))

(defn so []
  (-main [1 2 3 4 5]))
```

To test the above just call `(so)`. I added in `apply` to get rid of the double wrapping of the result. You could substitute `identity` for the above call to `f` (i.e. `(apply map identity args)`).

If you do want to `println` and return a value you can do that as well:

```
(defn probe
  ([x]
   (println x)
   x)
  ([x msg]
    (println msg x)
    x))
```

Just call `probe` instead of `f` or `identity` (i.e. `(apply map probe args)`). `probe` is a side-effecting `identity` function, where the side effect is to print the return value.

As a side note, if you do ever suspect that laziness is causing problems then wrap the return value in `seq`, or use `mapv` instead of `map`.

Comment: Just replacing map with mapv seems to produce an output in the terminal. I think you're on to something.

Comment: Plenty of experiments to do. Note that there can be two outputs going to the terminal - one from `println` and the other from the overall return value of the program you are running. For instance try `(mapv println [1 2 3])`. The return value will be `[nil nil nil]`, although you will also see the numbers being printed because of `println`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

1. `-main` is variadic, and the variadic variable (`args`) is what you're passing to `map`.  But you're calling `-main` as `(-main [1 2 3 4 5])`.  So `args` will be `([1 2 3 4 5])`.  So you are `map`ing not over a vector, but over a sequence containing a vector.

   Either define `-main` to take a single argument, or call `-main` as `(-main 1 2 3 4 5)`.
2. You make the classic error of mixing side-effects and laziness.  Sometimes this is useful, but often it's a mistake.  In your case, it's a mistake -- nothing will happen, because you never realize any of the values (which will all be `nil`, but the `println` will at least be executed as a side-effect).

   You can force the sequence via [`do-all`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall).  However, since the result is a sequence of `nil`s, you are really only interested in performing the side-effects rather than the actual values produced.  So [`dorun`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dorun) probably makes more sense.  But the most idiomatic way would be to use [`doseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) instead of `map`.  `doseq` is similar to [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) (which is basically logically equivalent to some syntactic sugar around `map`), except `doseq` is *not* lazy and does not produce a sequence -- it's purely for side-effects.